# Active geo replication, Auto failover groups and Read scale out in Azure

Tags: azure

What is the difference between Active geo replication, Auto failover groups and Read scale out in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Active Geo-replication provides replication of your primary database to a sec database in a different azure region.

Auto-Fail-over groups is a feature that provides automated management of the fail-over in case the primary server goes down, traffic will route to the secondary on its own.

Comment: Do you have any idea about read scale out?, How it's different from other two?

Comment: Yes, you can configure a secondary replica in the same region and offload read only queries to that server, by using read only listener string for it.